# How to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n^2)(1+2/n^2)\cdots(1+n/n^2)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can we compute the following limit:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n^2)(1+2/n^2)\cdots(1+n/n^2)$$

Mathematica gives the answer $\sqrt{e}$. However, I do not know to do it.

Comment: is it $1+\left(\frac 1n\right)^2$ instead of $1+\frac 1{n^2}?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee What is the difference?

Comment: @user17762, I mean for each term is it $1+\left(\frac rn\right)^2$ instead of $1+\frac r{n^2}?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think it is $1+\dfrac{r}{n^2}$, since it gives the limit as $\sqrt{e}$. Also, the product will diverge, it it were to be $1+\dfrac{r^2}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We will estimate
$$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left(1 + \dfrac{k}{n^2}\right)$$
Recall that $\log(1+x) = x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$. Hence, we get that
$$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{k}{n^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{k^2}{n^4}\right)\right) = \dfrac{n+1}{2n} + \mathcal{O}(1/n) \tag{$\star$}$$
where we made use of the fact that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k = \dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$.

Now letting $n \to \infty$ in $(\star)$, we get that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \dfrac12$$
The product you are interested in is $e^{f(n)}$ and since $e^x$ is continuous, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{f(n)} = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)} = e^{1/2} = \sqrt{e}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{1 + {1 \over n^{2}}}
\pars{1 + {2 \over n^{2}}}\cdots\pars{ 1 + {n \over n^{2}}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{n^{2} + 1}\pars{n^{2} + 2}\cdots\pars{n^{2} + n} \over n^{2n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{n^{2} + 1}^{\large\overline{n}} \over n^{2n}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\Gamma\pars{n^{2} + 1 + n}/\Gamma\pars{n^{2} + 1} \over n^{2n}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\pars{n^{2} + n}! \over n^{2n}\,\pars{n^{2}}!}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\root{2\pi}\pars{n^{2} + n}^{n^{2} + n + 1/2}\expo{-n^{2} - n} \over
n^{2n}\bracks{\root{2\pi}\pars{n^{2}}^{n^{2} + 1/2}\expo{-n^{2}}}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{n^{2n^{2} + 2n + 1}\ \pars{1 + 1/n}^{n^{2} + n + 1/2}\ \expo{-n} \over
n^{2n}\pars{n^{2n^{2} + 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{\bracks{n^{2} + n + {1 \over 2}}\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over n}} - n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{\bracks{n^{2} + n + {1 \over 2}}
\bracks{{1 \over n} - {1 \over 2n^{2}}} - n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{%
\bracks{n -{1 \over 2} + 1 - {1 \over 2n} + {1 \over 2n} - {1 \over 4n^{3}}} - n}} = \bbx{\ds{\root{\expo{}}}}\\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Nice approach +1. my previous deleted comment was due to the fact that sometimes the overline used in rising factorial is not visible on screen.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks. Maybe, you have some problem with your video. There's a $\texttt{\overline}$ there. I just  increased  it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I just checked it. Sometimes it's not visible after we reboot the page. If the problem persists I'll change the notation. I like this notation because it's very intuitive. It 'shows' that it's increasing.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort. It is now visible. the earlier version was visible only when I used zoom feature of mathjax. Surprisingly the mobile browser on android is better and it is able to display your earlier version too. Problem is probably my low resolution laptop.

Comment: I don't get the first equality.. what does $\overline n$ mean?

Comment: @Ant $\displaystyle a^{\overline{n}}$ defines the [Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). Namely, $\displaystyle a^{\overline{n}} \equiv a\left(a + 1\right)\left(a + 2\right)\ldots\left[a + \left(n - 1\right)\right] = \Gamma\left(a + n\right)/\Gamma\left(a\right)$. Note that I just inserted an additional step in the first line.

Comment: I believe there's a minor typo in your first equality: shouldn't the second factor be $(n^2+2)$?

Comment: @Patricio It’s true. I already fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For $1\le k\le n$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(1+{k\over n^2}\right)-{k\over n(n+1)}
&=\int_1^{1+k/n^2}{dt\over t}-{k\over n(n+1)}\\
&=\int_0^{k/n^2}\left({1\over1+t}-{n\over n+1}\right)dt\\
&={1\over n+1}\int_0^{k/n^2}\left(1-tn\over1+t \right)dt\\
&\le{1\over n+1}\int_0^{k/n^2}dt\\
&\le{k\over n^2(n+1)}\\
&\le{1\over n(n+1)}
\end{align}$$

Note, the integral in the third line is clearly non-negative, which means the initial expression is also non-negative.  Therefore

$$0\le\log\left(1+{k\over n^2}\right)-{k\over n(n+1)}\le{1\over n(n+1)}$$

Consequently, since $1+2+\cdots+n={n(n+1)\over2}$, we have

$$0\le\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+{k\over n^2}\right)-{1\over 2}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\log\left(1+{k\over n^2}\right)-{k\over n(n+1)}\right)\le{1\over n+1}$$

so by the Squeeze Theorem

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+{k\over n^2}\right)={1\over2}$$

and thus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n^2)(1+2/n^2)\cdots(1+n/n^2)=e^{1/2}=\sqrt e$$

Answer (score 0):

Using

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac an\right)^n=e^a$$

We have

\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\left((1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2}{n^2})(1+\frac{3}{n^2})\cdots(1+\frac {n}
{n^2})\right)^{n^2}\right]^{\frac1{n^2}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{1+\ldots+n}{n^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}=\sqrt e
\end{align}

Comment: This is wrong since the fact that, for every fixed $k$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{k,n}=x_k$$ does not imply in general that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^nx_{k,n}\right)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^{n^2}$$