# What will be the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2}{n^2})(1+\frac{3}{n^2})\cdots(1+\frac {n}{n^2}))$?

Tags: limits, binomial-theorem

> What will be the value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty} ((1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2}{n^2})(1+\frac{3}{n^2})\cdots(1+\frac {n}{n^2}))$$

My attempt was to use binomial expansion i.e. writing $(1+x^n)$ as $(1+nx)$ and the taking log on both sides. After that I tried using the method of integration for series limits but that led to a wrong answer. I am pretty sure the answer will be 'e' raised to the power something but i am not able to make it out.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389155/how-to-calculate-lim-n-to-infty11-n212-n2-cdots1n-n2

Comment: I wonder why this didn't show up while I was writing this question. Anyways, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think it's because you did not type your question with Mathjax in your first version.

Comment: Yup!!! Maybe that was the reason.