# Prove that the sequence is monotonic and bounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to prove that the following sequence is convergent $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{3}{n^2}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{n}{n^2}\right).$$

Certainly, I know how to determine the limit of that sequence. But I am asked to prove that it converges.

I was thinking of saying that it is monotonic and bounded and therefore converges, but I don't quite know how to do it, any help?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389155/how-to-calculate-lim-n-to-infty11-n212-n2-cdots1n-n2

Comment: This is a duplicate, as pointed out in your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4380363/42969.

Comment: That is to say that a sufficient argument to prove that it is convergent, is to express the limit? given that I am asked to prove that it converge

Comment: Boundedness can be obtained by applying inequality $1+x\le e^x.$  Proving monotonicity can be nasty. I would rather use the inequality $1+x\ge e^{x-x^2/2}$ for $0\le x<1.$